# Get directory names inside a folder?

Tags: java, android, directory

Hey, Is it possible to get all the folders names that are inside a folder?
A way to do that is: (File.getList()).isDirectory  but is there a better way than this? Thanks.

Comment: I don't think so, that sounds pretty solid. Why do you need to know directory names?

Comment: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=68

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that use [`File.listFiles()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28%29), then checking [`isDirectory()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#isDirectory%28%29) on each, is a fine solution.

If you want to get fancy, you could use [`File.listFiles(FileFilter)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28java.io.FileFilter%29), then implement a [`FileFilter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileFilter.html) that only accepts files that pass the `isDirectory()` test.  It would essentially be the same solution but could possibly simplify your code.